Stackoverflow when attempting arithmetic between classes
I have a simple class that contains basic skill attributes for a game. Each player has this skills class attached. I'd like to be able to do basic arithmetic, e.g. playerSkills = playerSkills + 2, and it would go through and add 2 to everything within the class, or perhaps I'd want to add two classes together like playerSkills3 = playerSkills2 + playerSkills1.
I've tried using overload operators but I get a stack overflow when calling them?
Any thoughts would be much appreciated.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerSkillsClass
{

    // Technical
    public float speed;
    public float agility;
    public float jump;
    public float strength;

    public static PlayerSkillsClass operator *(PlayerSkillsClass multiplyThis, PlayerSkillsClass withThis)
    {
        PlayerSkillsClass result = multiplyThis * withThis; //...multiply the 2 Coords
        return result;
    }

    public static PlayerSkillsClass operator *(PlayerSkillsClass multiplyThis, float withThis)
    {
        PlayerSkillsClass result = multiplyThis * withThis; //...multiply the Coord with the float
        return result;
    }
    public static PlayerSkillsClass operator +(PlayerSkillsClass addThis, PlayerSkillsClass withThis)
    {
        PlayerSkillsClass result = addThis + withThis; //...multiply the 2 Coords
        return result;
    }

    public static PlayerSkillsClass operator +(PlayerSkillsClass addThis, float withThis)
    {
        PlayerSkillsClass result = addThis + withThis; //...multiply the Coord with the float
        return result;
    }

}

I get this StackOverflow error, which is repeated for every element in the class i'm adding together:
StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
PlayerSkillsClass.op_Addition (PlayerSkillsClass addThis, System.Single withThis) <0x17a6a1af0 + 0x00004> in
Note that this class will have dozens of skills and I'll be adding and removing skills over time so I don't want to write manual functions to add/multiple/subtract etc every skill 1 by 1 (I had that before)

Useful reading: stack overflow

This is because you are using the + operator in the function that overloads its use.
When you look at the exception
StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow. PlayerSkillsClass.op_Addition (PlayerSkillsClass addThis, System.Single withThis) <0x17a6a1af0 + 0x00004> in

You can see that overloading + operator produces the method PlayerSkillsClass.op_Addition.
So, whenever you use + again the C# Compiler will replace it with calls to PlayerSkillsClass.op_Addition. Your code ends up looking something like this
op_Addition(addThis, withThis)
{
    var result = op_Addition(addThis,withThis);
    return result;
}

It's a bottomless recursion, so logically it ends up with StackOverflowException.

Look at the + operator. You define A + B as (return A + B) - but A + B just uses the same operator, resulting in infinite recursion and eventually a stack overflow.
I suspect you want to return a new PlayerSkillsClass object that adds the value of withThis to each of the properties:
public static PlayerSkillsClass operator +(PlayerSkillsClass addThis, float withThis)
{
    return new PlayerSkillsClass {
        speed    =  addThis.speed    + withThis,
        agility  =  addThis.agility  + withThis,
        strength =  addThis.strength + withThis,
        strength =  addThis.strength + withThis
    }
}


Note that this class will have dozens of skills and I'll be adding and removing skills over time so I don't want to write manual functions to add/multiple/subtract etc every skill 1 by 1 (I had that before)

Then you could design your skills as dynamic name-value pairs, looping through them to add/multiply/subtract to each value. You just lose strong-typing if you do not define actual properties.
